# /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-txqueulen.rules - file not generated

Tags: linux, unix, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have executed the below salt command, it is working fine but the file is not generated **(/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-txqueulen.rules )**

`salt '*Sriov*' cmd.run "printf 'KERNEL==\"tap[0-9,-,A-Z,a-z]*\", RUN+=\"/sbin/ip link set %%k txqueuelen 30000\"\\nKERNEL==\"qv[0-9,-,A-Z,a-z]*\", RUN+=\"/sbin/ip link set %%k txqueuelen 30000\"\\nKERNEL==\"qb[0-9,-,A-Z,a-z]*\", RUN+=\"/sbin/ip link set %%k txqueuelen 30000\"\\nKERNEL==\"en[0-9,-,A-Z,a-z]*\", RUN+=\"/sbin/ip link set %%k txqueuelen 30000\"\\n' > /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-txqueulen.rules; udevadm control --reload-rules; udevadm trigger"`

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser, so what's the question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I have executed this command but that file is not created because it is showing the error is permission denied so how to create that file with salt command

Comment: if you ran `salt` unprivileged, that could be the reason. Have you tried `sudo`? Not just any user can write to `/etc` and thereabouts.

Comment: (Really though, if you already have Salt, then this is really something you should deploy via Salt `file.managed` state, and not via ad-hoc commands...)

Comment: How can we use sudo in salt command